# Extjs how to get to the right component

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am creating a Sencha touch xtype, it will contain an invisible input file and a button; I would like to trigger the popup to choose a file when the button is pressed. This is what I've done so far:

```
config: {
    baseCls: 'imageFileField',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            baseCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-label'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            flex: 1,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    hidden: true,
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function (cmp) {
                            cmp.fileInputEl.set({
                                accept: 'image/*'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    baseCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'form-label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    margin: '5px',
                    docked: 'right',
                    ui: 'base_button',
                    iconCls: '',
                    width: '50px',
                    listeners: {
                        tap: function (view, e, eOpts) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

I know I should put something within the tap method, to navigate to the item and then trigger the event. I tried using this.up()/down(...) but I've never been able to get the invisible input. What is the right "path" to get there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.ComponentQuery to find you element and set its properties. To find your element you have to first assign itemId to it.

```
xtype: 'filefield',
hidden: true,
itemId: 'chooseFile',
listeners: {
              afterrender: function (cmp) {
                  cmp.fileInputEl.set({
                  accept: 'image/*'
                  });
               }
            }
```

Then you can put the following code in your button's listener event.

```
listeners: {
               tap: function (view, e, eOpts) {
                      Ext.ComponentQuery.query("container > #chooseFile").show();
                    }
           }
```

Comment: With  Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#chooseFile") I finally select it, but when the show() method doesn't display the popup to choose a file...

Comment: try  Ext.ComponentQuery.query("container > #chooseFile").hidden(false);

Comment: It's been a while since I've removed the 'hidden:true' line, it is not triggered.

Comment: Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#chooseFile")[0].show();

use [0] after parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

I have put all the controls in the controller and its working correctly:-

```
  refs: {
        filefield: 'filefield[name="fileField"]',
        fileBtn: 'button[name="fileBtn"]'
    },

    control: {
        "fileBtn": {
            tap: function() {
                this.getFilefield().show();
            }
        }
    }
```